# Scala equivalent of Haskell type constructor/inverse?

Tags: scala, haskell, types

I'm trying to port some code from Haskell to Scala and came across [this pair of functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.9.14/docs/Control-Compose.html#g:6):

[image: Screenshot from link]

> ```
> newtype OO f j a b
> ```
>
> Composition of type constructors: unary with binary. Called `StaticArrow` in [1].
>
> Constructors
>
> ```
> OO     
>     unOO :: f (a `j` b)
> ```

I tried to do this in Scala with something like

```
type OO[F[_], J[_, _], A, B] = F[J[A, B]]
```

but I think that's just `unOO`.

Can someone explain two things:
(1) What do `OO` and `unOO` actually do? (I think they're doing some type coercions, but I can't be sure why.)
(2) Is there an equivalent to these in Scala? Do I even need an equivalent to these in Scala?

For context, I'm trying to port the module [fungll-combinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fungll-combinators). There are examples of the use of `OO` and `unOO` in the file [Join.hs file](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fungll-combinators-0.1.0.1/src/src/GLL/Combinators/Visit/Join.hs)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors/documentation.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you looked at the actual definition? ``newtype OO f j a b = OO { unOO :: f (a `j` b) }``. `OO` is both a *type* constructor that maps a quadruple of types to a concrete type, as well as a *data* constructor essentially just wraps an appropriate value. `unOO` is the automatically generated inverse of `OO`, so that `OO . unOO == unOO . OO == id`.

Comment: If you didn't use record syntax to define this, it would be something like ``newtype OO f a j b = OO (f (a `j` b))`` with ``unOO :: OO f a j b -> f (a `j` b); unOO (OO x) = x``.

Comment: I'd guess that it might be something as simple as `case class OO[F[_], J[_, _], A, B](unOO: F[J[A, B]])`, but I'm not sure what exactly it's supposed to be used for. _"Do I even need an equivalent to these in Scala?"_ - this part makes the question too vague.

Comment: This was the key. I'm definitely a Haskell noob and I missed the fact that `OO` was a type and a data constructor. Once you pointed that out, wrapping and unwrapping make perfect sense.

Comment: @cafce25 I did link to the exact spot in the documentation that I added an image for and added a description saying that it was a screenshot of the link above. Should I have just left the screen shot out or tried to piece together something in a code block? (Actually asking, not trying to be argumentative.)

Comment: You should quote the documentation as text in the post, links to external resources are to be considered brittle because you might not have access to it everywhere (think China firewall) or it might change (admittedly unlikely in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The more you know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```hs
-- Haskell
data OO f j a b = OO { unOO :: f (a `j` b) }
```

corresponds to

```scala
// Scala
case class OO[F[_], J[_, _], A, B](unOO: F[A J B])
```

while

```hs
-- Haskell
newtype OO f j a b = OO { unOO :: f (a `j` b) }
```

corresponds to

```scala
// Scala
case class OO[F[_], J[_, _], A, B](unOO: F[A J B]) extends AnyVal
```

But [value classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) (`... extends AnyVal`) have limitations: [1](https://failex.blogspot.com/2017/04/the-high-cost-of-anyval-subclasses.html) [2](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12271).

Besides value classes, `newtype` can be implemented in Scala with the library [scala-newtype](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype) (Scala 2)

```scala
import io.estatico.newtype.macros.newtype

@newtype case class OO[F[_], J[_, _], A, B](unOO: F[A J B])

//scalac: {
//  type OO[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B] = OO.Type[F, J, A, B];
//  object OO extends scala.AnyRef {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    def apply[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B](unOO: F[J[A, B]]): OO[F, J, A, B] = unOO.asInstanceOf[OO[F, J, A, B]];
//    final implicit class Ops$newtype[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B] extends AnyVal {
//      <paramaccessor> val $this$: Type[F, J, A, B] = _;
//      def <init>($this$: Type[F, J, A, B]) = {
//        super.<init>();
//        ()
//      };
//      def unOO: F[J[A, B]] = $this$.asInstanceOf[F[J[A, B]]]
//    };
//    implicit def opsThis[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B](x: Ops$newtype[F, J, A, B]): Type[F, J, A, B] = x.$this$;
//    @new _root_.scala.inline() implicit def unsafeWrap[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B]: Coercible[Repr[F, J, A, B], Type[F, J, A, B]] = Coercible.instance;
//    @new _root_.scala.inline() implicit def unsafeUnwrap[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B]: Coercible[Type[F, J, A, B], Repr[F, J, A, B]] = Coercible.instance;
//    @new _root_.scala.inline() implicit def unsafeWrapM[M[_], F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B]: Coercible[M[Repr[F, J, A, B]], M[Type[F, J, A, B]]] = Coercible.instance;
//    @new _root_.scala.inline() implicit def unsafeUnwrapM[M[_], F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B]: Coercible[M[Type[F, J, A, B]], M[Repr[F, J, A, B]]] = Coercible.instance;
//    @new _root_.scala.inline() implicit def unsafeWrapK[T[_[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B]]]: Coercible[T[Repr], T[Type]] = Coercible.instance;
//    @new _root_.scala.inline() implicit def unsafeUnwrapK[T[_[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B]]]: Coercible[T[Type], T[Repr]] = Coercible.instance;
//    @new _root_.scala.inline() implicit def cannotWrapArrayAmbiguous1[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B]: Coercible[_root_.scala.Array[Repr[F, J, A, B]], _root_.scala.Array[Type[F, J, A, B]]] = Coercible.instance;
//    @new _root_.scala.inline() implicit def cannotWrapArrayAmbiguous2[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B]: Coercible[_root_.scala.Array[Repr[F, J, A, B]], _root_.scala.Array[Type[F, J, A, B]]] = Coercible.instance;
//    @new _root_.scala.inline() implicit def cannotUnwrapArrayAmbiguous1[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B]: Coercible[_root_.scala.Array[Type[F, J, A, B]], _root_.scala.Array[Repr[F, J, A, B]]] = Coercible.instance;
//    @new _root_.scala.inline() implicit def cannotUnwrapArrayAmbiguous2[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B]: Coercible[_root_.scala.Array[Type[F, J, A, B]], _root_.scala.Array[Repr[F, J, A, B]]] = Coercible.instance;
//    def deriving[TC$macro$1[_], F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B](implicit ev: TC$macro$1[Repr[F, J, A, B]]): TC$macro$1[Type[F, J, A, B]] = ev.asInstanceOf[TC$macro$1[Type[F, J, A, B]]];
//    def derivingK[TC$macro$1[_[_[_$$1], _[_$$2, _$$3], _, _]]](implicit ev: TC$macro$1[Repr]): TC$macro$1[Type] = ev.asInstanceOf[TC$macro$1[Type]];
//    type Repr[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B] = F[J[A, B]];
//    type Base = _root_.scala.Any {
//      type __OO__newtype
//    };
//    abstract trait Tag[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B] extends _root_.scala.Any;
//    type Type[F[_$$1], J[_$$2, _$$3], A, B] <: Base with Tag[F, J, A, B]
//  };
//  ()
//}
```

and [opaque types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/opaques.html) (Scala 3)

```scala
// outside the current scope it's not known that OO is F[A J B]

opaque type OO[F[_], J[_, _], A, B] = F[A J B]

object OO:
  def apply[F[_], J[_, _], A, B](x: F[A J B]): OO[F, J, A, B] = x
  def unOO[F[_], J[_, _], A, B](x: OO[F, J, A, B]): F[A J B] = x
```

Comment: `F[A J B]`...  Maybe at least something like `case class OO[F[_], ~[_, _], A, B](unOO: F[A ~ B])`, so that one at least is warned that the `~`-gizmo is probably special, probably something with infix type constructors? I mean, how many casual users would even be able to parse what `F[A J B]` is.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I wanted to be literal

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I'm still confused about Haskell's type declarations and constructor declarations. I missed the fact that `OO` was both a type and a wrapper.

Comment: Yeah, no offense Dmytro, but I'm going to write it as `F[J[A, B]]`. :-) (Although I am starting to enjoy the ability to infix functions with backticks in Haskell. It's quite convenient at times, and there's an explicit signal that something is happening, so it's less likely to confuse readers than implicit conversions or similar.)

Comment: @ToddO'Bryan Yeah, in Scala you can prefer some more meaningful names like `case class Composition[Unary[_], Binary[_, _], A, B](value: Unary[Binary[A, B]]) extends AnyVal` or `case class Composition[F[_], MapsTo[_, _], A, B](value: F[A MapsTo B]) extends AnyVal`. `unX`/`runX` is Haskell naming convention. Using the same name (like `value` in my examples) doesn't pollute global naming space because it's class-specific in Scala.

Comment: @ToddO'Bryan I added some explanation about `@newtype` and opaque types

Comment: https://github.com/kitlangton/neotype

Comment: https://newtypes.monix.io/